# Draw circle in console using python

Tags: python, geometry

I want to draw a circle in the console using characters instead of pixels, for this I need to know how many pixels are in each row.
The diameter is given as input, you need to output a list with the width in pixels of each line of the picture

For example:

**input: 7**

**output: [3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 3]**

[image]

**input: 12**

**output: [4, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 10, 10, 8, 4]**

[image]

How can this be implemented?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  Have you tried anything? Unless you can show what you've tried and explain where you got stuck we cannot possibly start helping you!.  Do you know how to print to the console? Do you know how to loop? Do you have python installed?  Do you understand the problem? Are you trying to 'draw a circle' as per the question title, or 'output how many characters would be used per line to draw a circle'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a good reminder for me to be careful when mixing zero-based and one-based computations. In this case, I had to account for the `for` loops being zero-based, but the quotient of the diameter divided by 2 being one-based. Otherwise, the plots would have been over or under by 1.

By the way, while I matched your answer for `7`, I didn't come up with the same exact plot for `12`:

> **NOTE** - Tested using Python 3.9.6

```
pixels_in_line = 0
pixels_per_line = []

diameter = int(input('Enter the diameter of the circle: '))

# You must account for the loops being zero-based, but the quotient of the diameter / 2 being
# one-based. If you use the exact radius, you will be short one column and one row.
offset_radius = (diameter / 2) - 0.5

for i in range(diameter):
    for j in range(diameter):
        x = i - offset_radius
        y = j - offset_radius
        if x * x + y * y <= offset_radius * offset_radius + 1:
            print('*', end='  ')
            pixels_in_line += 1
        else:
            print(' ', end='  ')
    pixels_per_line.append(pixels_in_line)
    pixels_in_line = 0
    print()

print('The pixels per line are {0}.'.format(pixels_per_line))
```

**Output for 7:**

```
Enter the diameter of the circle: 7
      *  *  *        
   *  *  *  *  *     
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  
   *  *  *  *  *     
      *  *  *        
The pixels per line are [3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 3].
```

**Output for 12:**

```
Enter the diameter of the circle: 12
               *  *                 
         *  *  *  *  *  *           
      *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *        
   *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     
   *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  
   *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     
   *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     
      *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *        
         *  *  *  *  *  *           
               *  *                 
The pixels per line are [2, 6, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12, 10, 10, 8, 6, 2].
```

Comment: Cool! Congrats. I'd propose instead of `if x * x + y * y <= offset_radius * offset_radius + 1:` to use: `if x ** 2 + y ** 2 <= offset_radius ** 2 + 1:`. And by the way, you can put all `*` in one string (join the lines with '\n') and print the string in one step. Don't need to print every `pixel` and don't need to count every `*` inside the loop (they can be counted with `list.count('*')` method). I think it would be a more clean code, just three steps: (1) make the string, (2) print the string, (3) count the 'pixels' per lines in the string and pint the report.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Rob's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70724637/14265469) (**all credits to Rob!**) I've managed to tweak the code for 12x12 pixel grid as well:

```
diameter = 12

radius = diameter / 2 - .5
r = (radius + .25)**2 + 1

result = ''

for i in range(diameter):
    y = (i - radius)**2
    for j in range(diameter):
        x = (j - radius)**2
        if x + y <= r:
            result = result + '*  '
        else:
            result = result + '   '
    result = result + '\n'

print(result)

result = result.split('\n')[:-1]
pixels_per_line = [x.count('*') for x in result]

print(f'The pixels per line are {pixels_per_line}.')
```

**Output:**

```
            *  *  *  *              
      *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *        
   *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     
   *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  
   *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     
   *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     
      *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *        
            *  *  *  *              

The pixels per line are [4, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 10, 10, 8, 4].
```

If you need the empty area inside the circle it can be done with minimal changes:

```
diameter = 7

radius = diameter / 2 - .5
r = (radius + .25)**2 + 1
r_min = (radius - 1)**2 + 1 # <-------- here

result = ''

for i in range(diameter):
    y = (i - radius)**2
    for j in range(diameter):
        x = (j - radius)**2
        if r_min <= x + y <= r: # <----- here
            result = result + '*  '
        else:
            result = result + '   '
    result = result + '\n'

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
      *  *  *        
   *  *     *  *     
*  *           *  *  
*                 *  
*  *           *  *  
   *  *     *  *     
      *  *  *
```

```
            *  *  *  *              
      *  *  *        *  *  *        
   *  *                    *  *     
   *                          *     
*  *                          *  *  
*                                *  
*                                *  
*  *                          *  *  
   *                          *     
   *  *                    *  *     
      *  *  *        *  *  *        
            *  *  *  *
```

Comment: @Ilya it would be fair if you accept the Rob's answer instead. He did most of the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this. This is based on the circle formula x^2 + y^2 is equal to radius and any point inside is less than radius.

```py
import math
radius = 10
for i in range(-radius,radius+1):
    for j in range(-radius, radius +1):
        if radius-1 <= math.sqrt(i**2 + j**2) <= radius:
            print("*",end = " ")
        else:
            print(" ", end = ' ')
    print()
```

Output is as follows

```py
                       *                         
                * * * * * * * * *                 
            * *                   * *             
          *                           *           
        *                               *         
      *                                   *       
    *                                       *     
    *                                       *     
  *                                           *   
  *                                           *   
  *                                           *   
  *                                           *   
* *                                           * * 
  *                                           *   
  *                                           *   
  *                                           *   
  *                                           *   
    *                                       *     
    *                                       *     
      *                                   *       
        *                               *         
          *                           *           
            * *                   * *             
                * * * * * * * * *                 
                        *
```

if you remove the greater than condition

```py
radius = 12
for i in range(-radius,radius+1):
    for j in range(-radius, radius +1):
        if math.sqrt(i**2 + j**2) <= radius:
            print("*",end = " ")
        else:
            print(" ", end = ' ')
    print()
```

output

```py
                       *                         
                * * * * * * * * *                 
            * * * * * * * * * * * * *             
          * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *           
        * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *         
      * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *       
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *     
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *     
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *     
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *     
      * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *       
        * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *         
          * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *           
            * * * * * * * * * * * * *             
                * * * * * * * * *                 
                        *
```